# Generate all RSpec spec files from existing controllers, models & views in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, tdd

Does anyone know of a rake task or RSpec call that will generate a bunch of empty files relative to the existing controllers, models, helper files and views that already exist within your application?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best solution for this is to add hooks in place within `environment.rb` to create the **spec.rb** files within the rails application each time a model or controller is created.

Here's the code for that (using RSpec and FactoryGirl):

```
module RailsApp

  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.generators do |g|
      g.test_framework  :rspec, :fixture_replacement => :factory_girl, :views => true, :helper => false
      g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, :dir => 'spec/factories'
      g.stylesheets     false
      g.javascripts     false
      g.helper          false
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: how to run that in existing models and controllers ?

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can generate an empty scaffold set of rspec tests against an existing controller using something like this:

```
rails generate rspec:scaffold recipe
```

You can improve on this by passing the attributes of the model you want to generate against, like this:

```
rails generate rspec:scaffold recipe title: string slug: string description: text
```

You'll still need to do some manual editing, but this should get you most of the way there.

Answer (score -4):

This should work:

1. Install the [rspec-rails gem](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec-rails) by adding it to your development and test groups in your gemfile `gem 'rspec-rails'`
2. Run the rspec generator from inside your app `rails generate rspec:install`
3. Read over this doc quickly to see how it integrates with your rails app [RSpec-rails doc](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/frames)

Comment: I've already run this comment before and all it does is create the .rspec, spec/ and spec/spec_helper.rb files :(

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.